# Calculating items that were entered into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the data that was entered into an array.

The JavaScript

```
function getInput() 
{
    var even = [];
    var odd = [];
    var num = prompt("Enter your number");
    if (num % 2 === 0) {
        alert("Data entered into array.");
        even.push(num);
    }
    else if (num % 2 == 1) {
        alert("Data entered into array.");
        odd.push(num)
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid input.");
    }
}
function finished() //This is where the calculations are done. It's accessed by a button in my HTML.
{
    var sum = document.getElementById("leftSumOutput").innerHTML = even[];
}
```

This is the structure for the page. I'm trying to use tables to store the outputs.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assignmentOne.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assignmentOne.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <div align=center>
        <h1>Welcome to Assignment One!</h1>
        <label for="input">Click for each time you would like to make an input ==></label>
        <button id="input" onclick="getInput()"><b>Click to input data</b></button><br><br>
        <button id="done" onclick="finished()">Click here when done</button>
        <!--<h1 id="even">Even</h1>
        <h1 id="odd">Odd</h1>
        <p id="left"></p>
        <p id="right"></p>
        <p id="leftResult"></p>
        <p id="rightResult"></p>-->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Even</th>
                <th>Odd</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td id="even"></td>
                <td id="odd"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr colspan="2">
                <td>Sum</td>
                <td id="leftSumOutput"></td>
                <td id="rightSumOutput"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr colspan="2">
                <td>Average</td>
                <td id="leftAvgOutput"></td>
                <td id="rightAvgOutput"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to calculate the items within the array. I'm a novice, so I apologize in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I don't know how to calculate the averages of the fields either. Any help with that would be appreciated. Thanks everyone for your assistance so far!

Comment: Where are you calling `finished()` from?

Comment: finished() is from my HTML and it's a button. It's outputting within a table I created within the HTML. The button is supposed to take the numbers from the arrays and output the sums and averages of the even and odd numbers, respectively.

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Do you mean there are even and odd arrays and you want to calculate them after the user had typed numbers many times? or say each time?

Comment: There's an even array and an odd array. The main function asks for the users input, then stores it in its respective array. The finished() function is going to take that data, perform calculations, and output it to a cell on the table.

Comment: One thing that you need to fix is you define your arrays in `getInput()`'s scope so they won't be accessible in `finished()`. You could make your arrays global variables.

Comment: Second thing you need to loop through your array in the `finished()` method and add all the elements together to get your sum.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are little bit confused with scoping of variables.
Here is an example of how it could've been done:

```js
(function(w, d) {
  
  var odds = [], evens = [], button, elSumOdds,elSumEvens, elAvgOdds, elAvgEvens, s

  w.addEventListener('load', function() {
    button = d.querySelector('button')
    elSumOdds = d.querySelector('#sum-odds')
    elSumEvens = d.querySelector('#sum-evens')      
    elAvgOdds = d.querySelector('#avg-odds')
    elAvgEvens = d.querySelector('#avg-evens')      
    button.addEventListener('click', calculate)    
  })
  
  function calculate() {
  
    var i = prompt('enter number') | 0;           

    if ((i|0)%2) {
       odds.push(i)
       s = odds.reduce(function(a,n) { return  a+n }, 0)
       elSumOdds.innerText = s
       elAvgOdds.innerText = s / odds.length
    } else {
       evens.push(i)
       s = evens.reduce(function(a,n) { return  a+n }, 0)  
       elSumEvens.innerText = s
       elAvgEvens.innerText = s / evens.length
    }       
  }

})(window, document)
```

```html
<button > calculate</button>

<table>
  <tr><td></td><td>Sum</td><td>Avg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Odds</td><td id='sum-odds'></td><td id='avg-odds'></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Evens</td><td id='sum-evens'></td><td id='avg-evens'></td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: liked your structure :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate sum of each element in array you need to write `map` function. Visit link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

if you just need to know amount of elements, call:  `alert(even.length);`

Answer (score 0):

*Note: @vittore 's structure inspired this change.*

```js
(function(d) {

  d.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', getInput);
  d.getElementById('done').addEventListener('click', finished);

  var elSumOdd = d.getElementById('oddSumOutput');
  var elSumEven = d.getElementById('evenSumOutput');
  var elAvgOdd = d.getElementById('oddAvgOutput');
  var elAvgEven = d.getElementById('evenAvgOutput');

  var even = [];
  var odd = [];

  function getInput() {
    var num = prompt("Enter your number") | 0;
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      even.push(num);
    } else if (num % 2 == 1) {
      odd.push(num);
    } else {
      alert("Invalid input.");
    }

    finished();
  }

  function finished() { //This is where the calculations are done. It's accessed by a button in my HTML.
    elSumOdd.innerHTML = odd.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);

    elSumEven.innerHTML = even.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);

    elAvgOdd.innerHTML = elSumOdd.innerHTML / odd.length || 0;
    elAvgEven.innerHTML = elSumEven.innerHTML / even.length || 0;
  }

})(document);
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <h1>Welcome to Assignment One!</h1>
  <label for="input">Click for each time you would like to make an input ==></label>
  <button id="input"><b>Click to input data</b>
  </button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="done">Click here when done</button>
  <!--<h1 id="even">Even</h1>
        <h1 id="odd">Odd</h1>
        <p id="left"></p>
        <p id="right"></p>
        <p id="leftResult"></p>
        <p id="rightResult"></p>-->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Even</th>
      <th>Odd</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="even"></td>
      <td id="odd"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan="2">
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td id="evenSumOutput"></td>
      <td id="oddSumOutput"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan="2">
      <td>Average</td>
      <td id="evenAvgOutput"></td>
      <td id="oddAvgOutput"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly did you do with that odd: function() part? I haven't seen that before.